# Checking if a user is logged in, if so redirect to a different page

Tags: wp-redirect

I'm making a member-only site that requires users to be logged in to use the site.

The homepage is publicly viewable. On the homepage, I'd like to put in a function to redirect users to a page inside the site if they are logged in.

The code I tried

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
 wp_redirect ('dashboard' );
 exit;
 }
?>
```

Gives me a "headers already sent" error. The code is placed at the top of my php file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it say where the headers ate sent from?

Comment: /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934

Comment: try turning on wp_debug and see whats going on there

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you just simplified for example, but make sure you use full URL in [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) call.

Also rather than having it in template, I think it would be more appropriate to run this at `template_redirect` hook.

Comment: My solution is `wp_redirect ( home_url("/dashboard") );`, and I've put this code on line 1 of the template. Although I'm not familiar with hooks so you probably have a valid point. Why?

Comment: @javy `template_redirect` is semantically place in code like "WP knows what it needs to start loading and outputting, but you can change its mind". Start of template is "we are already loading this thing". If you don't want what's in template there is no reason to get that far in the process.

Comment: Makes sense, sounds like it saves some server utilization?

Comment: @javy I don't think difference in performance would be meaningful between too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect ( home_url("/dashboard") );
exit;
}
?>
```

Is what I've come up with, and works. Also, I think I also messed up by putting this below

```
<?php
/*Template Name: Home*/
?>
```

The new code is on line 1 and works.